# Append list called with iterate

Tags: python-3.x

I have a simple issue with my code in Python 3.6.

I am reading a csv and storing int values in a list called Total.
I ask Python user to enter a number n=.. (in this example n=9). 
I create n (9) empty list with :

```
for j in range (1,n+1):
    command=""
    command="list"+str(j)+"=[]
```

Now, I have list1, list2, ... list9

Then, I want to append these lists by reading Total starting at different elements and reading each n (9) elements.

For example:

```
list1=[Tot[0],Tot[8]...] list2=[Tot[1],Tot[9],...]
```

To do so, I want to something like

```
for k in range (0,n):
    for a in range (0+k,len(Total),n):
        listk.append(Total[a])
```

My problem is here, Python doesn't recognise the integer in listk such as:

```
list1, ... list9
```

Is there a certain way to do it ? Maybe by using a class ?

Comment: How do you mean it doesn't recognise the integer?  Is there an error message that it gives, if so then please post that also.  Is `listk.append ` supposed to replace the k to make it list1/2/3/4 etc. if so then this won't work, python will interpret that listk is a new list not that it should be list1/2/3/4 etc.

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem I suggest using a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp). A dictionary is a type of data structure in python that allows to store pairs of information - for example lists and their names. This way you can create n separate named lists, store them all inside one dictionary, and append them as necessary. To start at different indices, I make use of the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator.

This should do the trick:

```
# shorthand syntax for creating a dictionary with n empty lists: list1,...,listn
    lists = {"list" + str(i + 1): [] for i in range(n)}
    for k in range(n):
        list = lists.get("list" + str(k + 1))
        for j in range(n):
            list.append(Total[(j + k) % n])
```

A few sidenotes:

It seems you have a few misunderstandings concerning Python syntax. When you declare the variable "command" inside your loop, Python is saving a *pointer* to a specific place in stack memory. However you are inside a loop, so "command" is overwritten in every iteration of the loop, and the old pointer is lost.

The following line:

```
command="list"+str(j)+"=[]
```

is invalid in Python. The syntax to create lists using square brackets is:

```
variable = [item1, item2, item3] # or variable = [] for an empty list
```

You cannot mix between strings and list creation in the way you attempted to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped a lot !

Comment: Happy to help and welcome to Stack Overflow :)
If you feel this answer or any other on this site has solved your problem, please consider marking it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps other users find answers to their questions and keeps the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.